# using count and group by correctly

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have a relation CandyC(**id**, email, age, name, candy_id)
I want to count the CandyC.ids associated with a CandyC.candy_id once.

Attempt:

```
SELECT email, age, name
FROM CandyC
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT candy_id) = 1;
```

It gives me an error:
not a group by expression

Comment: `having` comes after `group by`. and `group by` should include all the non-aggregated columns in `select`.

Comment: @vkp - Oracle supports it before group by too.

Comment: @GurV, yeah ... Oracle is Non-ANSI compliant...

Answer (score 0):

The `group by` clause need to have all the non aggregated columns selected directly. Also, it's usually a good idea to use `having` after the `group by` as it's the standard way of writing this (even though Oracle supports it the other way too).

Does this do what you want:

```
select email, age, name
from candyc
group by id, email, age, name
having count(distinct candy_id) = 1
```

If not, you should provide sample data and expected results in your question to clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something more like this:

```
SELECT candy_id, COUNT(*)
FROM CandyC
GROUP BY candy_id;
```

I don't know what the `email`/`age`/`name` columns have to do with the question:

> I want to count the CandyC.ids associated with a CandyC.candy_id once.